# which one to read first to develop mobile application

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

I am bit confusion on reading the books html 5 and jQuery. which one is the first to read and understand the basic for another technology.

I am looking for developing a small mobile application. so i had this confusion to read it.

Thanks,
Ravi

Comment: It's unclear what your question is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are familiar with Html 4, then you can take jQuery first and then Html 5. Else, take Html 5 first and then jQuery. After than you can take a look at [jQuery mobile](http://jquerymobile.com) library.
If you are not familiar with JavaScript, then first you need to learn JavaScript before taking up jQuery. JavaScript is a programming language and you need to learn it just like any other programming language.